# (Python) Hash function returns different values depending on how the script is called (cmd vs IDE)

Tags: python, cmd, hash

I have a script that scrapes cell value data from an excel workbook into nested tuples.  Then it returns the hash of that tuple.  I can run it in my IDE (Spyder 4.0.1, Python 3.7), or I can call the function using command line.

The problem is that that hash is a different number depending on how I call it.  This should not be the case, as it should be pulling the same exact data from the same exact excel workbook, and then using the same exact hash function.  I already tried some debugging but I'm running out of ideas.  Thoughts?

The relevant code:

```
import extract #my own code, which contains open_excel()
import sys

#This function takes nested lists and turns them into nested tuples.
def list2tuple(l):
    lcopy = []
    for item in l:
        if type(item) == list:
            lcopy.append(list2tuple(item))
        else:
            lcopy.append(item)
    return tuple(lcopy)

def hashxl(filename):
    filetype = filename[filename.index('.')+1:]
    if filetype in ['xlsx','xlsb']:
        f = extract.open_excel(filename)  #This should be a list of lists of lists of data (sheets, rows, columns of excel data)
        h = hash(list2tuple(f))
        return h

if sys.argv[1] == 'hash':
    print(hashxl(sys.argv[2])
```

When I run

```
python thiscodefile.py hash testfile.xlsb
```

in command line I get -3482465542484766986.  When I run

```
hashxl("testfile.xlsb")
```

in the Spyder IDE I get 6187680721660987353.

Comment: "This should not be the case," Why do you believe that? You should *never* rely on the value returned by `hash` to be the same across different runs of your program. Indeed, anything about the precise value is likely dependant on implementation details you shouldn't rely on. The only necessary property is that it serve as a useful hash value for hashing based containers, like `dict`, `set` etc.

Comment: Note, `hash` is not supposed to provide a cryptographic hash, if that is what you were expecting.

Comment: In all the documentation I found, x = y implies that hash(x) = hash(y).  If I use hash(x) and then hash(x) again, then the result should be exactly the same, since x = x.  In this case, x represents the parsed file data from testfile.xlsb.  So since this data is identical to itself, the the hash function's result of the first call should be the same as the hash function's result on the second call, no?

Comment: No, not across different invocations of your program. Anyway, what sort of objects are you hashing exactly?

Comment: "x = y implies that hash(x) = hash(y)" is only true *within a single execution of Python*.  The result of `hash()` is _intentionally_ randomized between executions.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why that randomization isn't mentioned in any of the documentation I found pretty much anywhere.  I even started looking through the python source code to see if I could find something and didn't see anything that suggested randomness.
@juanpa.arrivillaga a list of lists of lists.  For example [ [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ], [ [7,8,9] ] ]. (I am "tuplifying" it before I hash it).

Comment: @Sam it doesnt have to be documented anywhere, it's an *implementation detail*. There *is no guarantee in the documentation/specification* of the property you are expecting. So anyway, you are literally just doing lists-of-lists-of-lists of ints?

Comment: The nested lists contain ints, floats, and strings.  I aim to make a unique code based on the values in the spreadsheet (but NOT the formatting).  At work I get sent the same file after small updates, and they're never sent with different names, so it's hard to tell them apart with just a glance.  Meanwhile they are each 50 sheets long filled with data.  So if I can get a unique hash-like code for the data, then supposedly it should be quick to check which files are the same and which are different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's normal because python uses a random hash seed to solve such problems,  [vulnerability disclosure](http://ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html). To solve your problem you can set a fixed seed using the [PYTHONHASHSEED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED).
The best and easiest way to do it is:

```
import os  
import sys
hashseed = os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED')
if not hashseed:
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
[your code here]
```